# How to get values from the xml value without mentioning its attribute's name in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

The below will works fine. But I want to read it dynamically without attributes or coulmn name

Sample xml

```
declare @xmlval xml='<ArrayOfCustomers>
   <Customer>
       <ItemId>1</ItemId>
       <Value>Mr Smith</Value>
   </Customer>
   <Customer>
      <ItemId>2</ItemId>
      <Value>Mr Bloggs</Value>
   </Customer>
</ArrayOfCustomers>'
```

Sample query

```
SELECT
   Cust.value('(ItemId)[1]', 'int') AS 'ItemID',
   Cust.value('(Value)[1]', 'Varchar(50)') AS 'Customer Name'
FROM
   @xmlval.nodes('/ArrayOfCustomers/Customer') AS AOC(Cust)
```

The above works fine. How to get values from the xml value without mentioning its attribute name in the select statement.

--Required query sample format
           For eg:

```
SELECT
   Cust.value('[0][1]', 'int') AS 'ItemID',
   Cust.value('[1][1]', 'Varchar(50)') AS 'Customer Name'
```

or

```
SELECT
   Cust.value('[1]', 'int') AS 'ItemID',
   Cust.value('[1]', 'Varchar(50)') AS 'Customer Name'
FROM
   @xmlval.nodes('/ArrayOfCustomers/Customer') AS AOC(Cust)
```

In our case I dont know about the column or attribute names for the input @xmlval value. I want to insert the xml value into new table (int,varchar(50))

Thanks,
Velsankar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can select all elements by `*` and then get first by `[1]` and second by `[2]`:

```
select
   Cust.value('*[1]', 'int') AS 'ItemID',
   Cust.value('*[2]', 'Varchar(50)') AS 'Customer Name'
from @xmlval.nodes('/ArrayOfCustomers/Customer') as AOC(Cust)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/23751)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to get values when number of columns or fields is unknown?

Comment: It's possible with dynamic SQL, but what output do you want to get? Usually it's bad idea to return dynamic number of columns from SQL Server

Comment: I will get a xml value in a table column. I have to return it as a table. Each row may have different xml value. So at the time of execution only I will know the number of columns and its attribute names. Kindly advise how to get the values as table

Comment: Do you process table in some client application after that? You'll have hard times to do this in SQL Server, it's much easier to do in some proper programming language

Comment: Yes. Ok. will do in client side.